# Access stored procedure return DAO.recordset

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2, and at the top there is this line

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

The stored procedure returns a value which is calculated by the stored procedure. I can't use functions (UDF) in SQL Server as I need the result in Access-VBA.

There is a logic like

```
IF blabla 
    SET @Result = 1 
ELSE 
    SET @Result = 0
```

followed at the end of the stored procedure :

```
SELECT @Result AS Status

RETURN @Result
```

I can start the stored procedure in SSMS like:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spDoStuff]
        @PAR_tableFlag = 1,          
        @PAR_DESC = N'PRNECEE901' 

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value GO
```

The "Return Value" displays a result as desired.

What's the simplest way to get the resultset in Access-VBA?

I had trouble with ADO - recordset is closed and so couldn't read rst(0).

Now I switched Code to DAO. Still trouble to simply read the "Return Value" into a recordset and do like

```
If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
    varReturn = rst(0)
End If
```

Comment: If your SQL produces multiple recordsets (even if some are empty), then you'll need to use `.NextRecordset` until you get to the recordset that has the records you want.

Comment: but I return just one recordset as I can see when I execute the SP in SSMS

Comment: meanwhile I found the issue: using some IF ... ELSE statements in the SP there was one ELSE left and the SP never ever could do the "SELECT col1 FROM tbl" at the end. And so there was no recordset to return - booaaahh - so much time lost - many of you know this scenario :.(